# how to get ajax response in a specific div with id

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, count, callback

For a simple click counter i use this code:

```
$clickcount = explode("\n", file_get_contents('counter.txt'));
foreach($clickcount as $line){
    $tmp = explode('||', $line);
    $count[trim($tmp[0])] = trim($tmp[1]);
}

?>

<button class="click-trigger float-left" data-click-id="click-001">Click</button> 
<span id="click-001" class="click-count float-left"><?php echo $count['click-001'];?></span>
<br/><br/>

<button class="click-trigger float-left" data-click-id="click-002">Click</button> 
<span id="click-002" class="click-count float-left"><?php echo $count['click-002'];?></span>
<br/><br/>

<button class="click-trigger float-left" data-click-id="click-003">Click</button> 
<span id="click-003" class="click-count float-left"><?php echo $count['click-003'];?></span>
<br/><br/>
```

I send the dat via ajax like below:

```
$('body').on('click', '.click-trigger', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var id = $(this).attr('data-click-id');

    $.ajax({
        url: 'counter.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: { id:id },                    
        success: function(data){
           $(id).html(data);    // replace the new number in this div (but does not work!)                                                                  
        },

    });

});
```

My php (counter.php)

```
$file = 'counter.txt'; // path to text file that stores counts
$fh = fopen($file, 'r+');
$id = $_POST['id']; 
$lines = '';
while(!feof($fh)){
    $line = explode('||', fgets($fh));
    $item = trim($line[0]);
    $num = trim($line[1]);
    if(!empty($item)){
        if($item == $id){
            $num++; // increment count by 1
            echo $num;  // send new number back to page     
            }
        $lines .= "$item||$num\r\n";
        }
    } 
file_put_contents($file, $lines);
fclose($fh);
```

The **id** of the span element which has the same name as **data-click-id** should give me the new number, but this does not work. What i am doing wrong?

After a hard refresh, the number increases by 1

Comment: `$(id)` will not select anything because the IDs in your data attributes are simple strings like `click-001`. But that isn't a valid selector. You'd need a `#` to select the correct place. e.g. `$("#"+id)` so that the final selector looks something like `$("#click-001")`. (And because the code doesn't select the right element, then clearly nothing can be output on the page. Add that to the symptom in Jay's answer below where the PHP script may not always output anything anyway, and you have a good recipe for not seeing any results).

Comment: I agree! `success: function(data){ $("#"+id).html(data); },` does the job. Thnx for solution